# Saving multiple check box values using Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, checkbox

I have multiple check boxes 32 to be exact.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="m1"> -> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="m32">
```

On my Javascript I am checking each check box if it is checked or not the I will assign a value 1 for checked and 0 for unchecked.

```
//I got 32 of these
if (document.getElementById("m1").checked){
    m1 = '1';
}
else{
    m1 = '0';
}
```

Then I am sending the data using Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'submit-user-details.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'TEXT',
    data: {firstname : firstname, lastname : lastname, middlename : middlename, usercd : usercd, password : password, usergrp : usergrp, userstatus : userstatus, branch : branch, m1 : m1, m2 : m2, m3 : m3, m4 : m4, m5 : m5, m6 : m6, m7 : m7, m8 : m8, m9 : m9, m10 : m10, m11 : m11, m12 : m12, m13 : m13, m14 : m14, m15 : m15, m16 : m16, m17 : m17, m18 : m18, m19 : m19, m20 : m20, m21 : m21, m22 : m22, m23 : m23, m24 : m24, m25 : m25, m26 : m26, m27 : m27, m28 : m28, m29 : m29, m30 : m30, m31 : m31, m32 : m32},
    success: function(response) {
        $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Then in my PHP, each value have their own Insert Query ***(Note: please ignore my query I know that this is not secured but I am currently using an old version of XAMPP there is no PDO support for Oracle)***.

```
//I got 32 of these
$modulerightsql = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO ASUSERMODULERIGHTS(USERCD, SWITCH, MODULEID) VALUES('". $usercd ."', '". $m32 ."', '32')");
oci_execute($modulerightsql);
```

Is there a better way to save the value of my check boxes better?

Comment: wouldn't it be much better to put all the modules in a separate table instead? just add the user id with it. imagine if it becomes a hundred or more modules to be added. you're making it painful to maintain

Comment: I have a table it is called ASUSERMODULERIGHTS it is in my php code

Comment: ORACLE supports prepared  statements.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner In my version it is not supported

Comment: @EncoreLeasingandFinanceCor yes i know i see that already in your php code above, see, you comment above says you got 32 repetitive codes that does it from 1 to 32. if you have normalised your table from the beginning you would've saved yourself from this trouble

Comment: Ok. Well, if you're looking for a PHP method to do this, you can run a `foreach` on `isset()` with key pairing.

Comment: My problem is how can I set a value to each checkbox like for example if a certain check box is not check the value is 0 then if check is 1. Another problem is sending that values to my PHP via ajax

Answer (score 1):

Send this multipleValue variable to ajax File. you get value.
example : m1,m2,m3

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    
   var multipleValue = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      multipleValue[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(multipleValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="m1" name="m[]" value="m1"> M1
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="m1" name="m[]" value="m2"> M2
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="m1" name="m[]" value="m3"> M3
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="m32" name="m[]" value="m32"> M32
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Comment: What if I need to check each check box if it is checked or not and assign a value to each check box 1 for check and 0 for unchecked

Answer (score 0):

Use array notation for checkboxes names:

```
<input type="checkbox" name = "m[]" class="custom-control-input" id="m1">
<input type="checkbox" name = "m[]" class="custom-control-input" id="m32">
```

In this case $_POST['m'] is going to be an array of checked values.

Comment: That doesn't fully answer what they're asking. This being about handling each of those selected that is.